# Delphi require 4 digit year

Tags: delphi

A user will enter a string value for a date.  StrToDate will be used to convert the string value to a DateTime.  If the user enter's a date with a 2 digit year the date may be parsed as the current century (20xx) or the previous century (19xx).

To clear up any ambiguity, how do require the user enter a 4 digit year?

```
if isFourDigitYear(txbDate.Text) then
  date := StrToDate(txbDate.Text)
else
  ShowMessage('enter date with 4 digit year');
```

Comment: @TLama I meant a date containing a 2 digit year, like 8/18/64.  edited the question to try to clarify

Comment: Use a format string that mandates 4 digit years. But then you'd have to choose the format string. Do you want to do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it'd be an option, but I don't see how to mandate 4 digit years in the format string.  My default ShortDateFormat is M/d/yyyy but StrToDate isn't requiring 4 digit years.  Is there some syntax to the format string to make 4 digits of yyyy required?

Comment: Then you'll need to parse the string yourself.

Comment: `if length(txbDate.Text)-(pos('/',copy(txbDate.Text,4,10))+3)=4 then showmessage('valid');`

Comment: You could use the [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit) control with `EditMask` !90/90/0000;1;? for example.

Comment: Why not use a `TDateTimePicker` instead? It is specifically designed for date/time input.

Comment: If you are so concerned about the year then I suggest you to use not 1 but 3 edit boxes for day, month and year and to provide quick navigation between them, i.e. after second char entered in month edit box automatically day editbox takes focus, if backspace is pressed focus goes back to month... And after all this input is over if the year is with 2 digits then if year <= 14 (current year) year is 2000+YearValue, else 1900+YearValue. `TDateTimePicker` requires pressing of delimiter key to switch month/day/year, with 3 edit boxes input will be faster.

Comment: If looks like you've already written the code to answer your own question. What further trouble are you having?

Comment: I haven't implemented the isFourDigitYear function, the example just show's how I'd intend to use it.

Comment: Use a TDateTimePicker, or use a TMaskEdit with the appropriate mask. Trying to do this in a standard TEdit means you're going to have to parse the input, which is a pain in the backside.

Comment: Using a TDateTimePicker or TMaskEdit would be a good approach, but in my scenario I'm stuck dealing with a string.  I'll edit to remove the bit about the TEdit control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is this:

```
FUNCTION IsFourDigitYear(DateStr : STRING ; DateSep : CHAR = '/') : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    P   : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    DateStr:=DateStr+DateSep; Result:=TRUE;
    REPEAT
      P:=POS(DateSep,DateStr);
      IF P=5 THEN EXIT;
      DELETE(DateStr,1,P)
    UNTIL DateStr='';
    Result:=FALSE
  END;
```

It will check that there is a part of the given string that has 4 characters.

It currently won't check if that part is numerical (ie. only contains digits). And it will require you to pass in the seperator character used if you want it to be truly international - there are some countries that use '-' as a date seperator, and most other countries in the world doesn't use the strange M/D/Y format, but either D/M/Y or Y/M/D format (where "/" may be "-" in some countries).

If you want a truly international function that also checks if the four-digit part is actually in the year part of the currently valid date format, then it'll need a much more complex parser. The above may get you started, however...

Comment: I added an exception if the ShortDateFormat isn't 'M/d/yyyy'.  If support for other date formats becomes an issue I'll add them as they come up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best choice would be to use TDateTimePicker

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker

If you are using older Delphi than Delphi 2009 with update pack 3 then you would wanna read next article to fix a bug found in TDateTimePicker.

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=117

This bug has been fixed in newer versions.

Now if you are using FireMonkey take care about using TDateTimePicker as in Delphi XE3 it has a bug which srews up the date when entered through keyboard (can still be picked fine by mouse). I'm not sure if this was already fixed in later versions of Delphi or not.

If using of TDateTimePicker is out of the question then definitly use TMaskedEdit instead of regular TEdit since the chosen mask forces user to enter in text in proper format.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/EditMask_(Delphi)

EDIT: The best advantage of using TDateTimePicker is that it automatically uses Date Time format that has been set on that specific system.

This means that date time format used will be the one user is used to. So there will be no mistakes in case if user local settings use dd/mm/yy format instead of mm/dd/yy.